# Waiting for asynchronous function, which doesn't take callback and doesn't return a promise, to be executed without changing the other function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am currently trying to add some functionality to an existing web app written in JavaScript. My Problem is that I want to call a function which again calls some asynchronous functions and I want to execute a function not before all other functions have been executed.

The function I am calling doesn't take a callback and also doesn't return a promise (which is of course very bad practise).

I could refactor the existing functions so that the function I am calling is returning a promise but this would require a great deal of time and effort.

So the ideal solution for me would be a technique which allows me to wait for the function I have called and all functions then again called by this function to be executed.

Another acceptable option would a technique which allows me to execute a function after all asynchronous functions have been executed.

So transferring this to an simple example, I would like to execute a function after the function `doSomethingAsync` has been executed without changing this function.

```
var doSomethingAsync = () => {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log("do Something Async") }, 1000);
};
// do something after doSomethingAsync has been executed ...
```

I tried with a setTimeout() and zero millisecs function but this doesn't work as it is executed before the `doSomethingAsync`function, and I know that in this simple example.

There are a lot of options to execute something after `doSomethingAsync`but I need a technique which allows me to execute something after `doSomethingAsync` without changing this function.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: I agree with Todd. If you cannot change `doSomethingAsync()` your only hope is looking for a side effect you can watch instead. For example, if doSomethingAsync creates a file on the hard disk, you could poll the file system every x miliseconds with a setInterval until the file is created and is readable, and then resolve the promise. A timeout won't do anything if you do not have something to wait for. It will just defer the problem until the day `doSomethingAsync()` takes longer than the timeout. What does `doSomethingAsync()` actually do? Then we can look for appropriate workarounds.

Comment: Yes, watching for a side effect is a good workaround. However the actual `doSomethingAsync` function is doing some complex things which I not fully understand. Basically the `doSomethingAsync` changes an object parameter, which informs some listener which than again call some functions. So It is very difficult to overlook what  `doSomethingAsync()` is actually doing :-(

Comment: Do you have access to that object? We can wrap that object inside a proxy or other structure, so we can write a setter function that can resolve our promise when the property of the object changes. Do you have access to the listener? We could reroute the listener through another listener that will resolve our promise again. So anything you can add code to or change of which you say, if this happens, doSomethingAsync() is finished will probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve what you want without changing `doSomethingAsync`. That function immediately finishes and leaves no way of detecting when that `setTimeout` finishes. Unless you can find some other side effect to monitor for, you are out of luck.

Well technically it would be easy to execute something immediately after `doSomethingAsync` finishes executing. It finishes almost immediately. What you can't do is to execute something after the `setTimeout` triggers. Because `doSomethingAsync` doesn't return any ties to what it did internally.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought as well. Even though I cannot understand why it is not possible in javascript.

Comment: What is still confusing you? There is absolutely no ties to the `setTimeout` in your code. Without ties to it, how would you possibly monitor it finishing? Put another way, the exact reason people use callbacks and promises is to allow such tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for the `await` keyword.

```
async function waitForMe() {
    console.log("I take time to execute")
}

async function waitsForOthers() {
    console.log("I am going to print right now")
    await waitForMe() //***
    console.log("Now that that's done, I am going to print")
}
```

Comment: waitsForOthers() should be the async function, since: `Remember, the await keyword is only valid inside async functions. If you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a SyntaxError.` And waitForMe() should return a promise in any real life example.

Comment: good catch on the missing async. Why should it return a promise?

Comment: Since the problem of the OP is that the function he wants to call does not return a promise or take a callback, I thought it was relevant to mention that it's useless to make the function async if it does not return anything since then the result of the promise will always be undefined or an error.

Comment: and if it does return something, should there still be a promise inside the async function?

Comment: Weird question. But sure. Inside the async function `waitsForOthers()`. ( `waitForMe()` does not need the async function keyword, since it does not await anything ) there can be anything. If people want to be able to await `waitsForOthers()`, it should return a promise as well. The point is, async functions that do not return a promise are equivalent to a synchronous function. If there's nothing to actually wait for, this is equivalent to just 3 console.log() calls directly after eachother, but only slower.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Lots of help for a js newb.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the above function as,

```js
var doSomethingAsync = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("do Something Async");
    youWantToExecuteAtLast();
  }, 1000);
};
// do something after doSomethingAsync has been executed ... 

function youWantToExecuteAtLast() {
  alert("This is the end");
};

doSomethingAsync();
```

For multiple calls,

```js
var counter = 0;
var doSomethingAsync = (timer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("do Something Async : ",(counter+1));
    counter++;
    youWantToExecuteAtLast();
  }, timer);
};
// do something after doSomethingAsync has been executed ... 

function youWantToExecuteAtLast() {
  if(counter === 3)
    alert("Three calls are done");
};

doSomethingAsync(2000);
doSomethingAsync(4000);
doSomethingAsync(6000);
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I need a technique without changing `doSomethingAsync` :-(

Comment: Please refer to, https://javascript.info/async-await Ask if not understood.